# Tela inicial de site - estrutura

Tags: html, css

Quero definir como página inicial do meu site uma imagem que ocupe todo o fundo, como segue:

```
<style type=text/css>
body {
    background-image: url("imagem.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
    -webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;}
}
</style>
```

Porém quero a mesma fixa no fundo (no lugar do fundo branco, que aparece normalmente) e por cima dessa imagem quero colocar o restante, que irá compor a tela. Rodapé, Topo, área de login, cadastro... Tudo posicionado sobre essa imagem, que será apenas o fundo. Posso fazer isso com div? Como procedo? Se alguém puder me orientar ou auxiliar com exemplo, agradeço.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Esse código que você postou deu algum problema?

Comment: Não, carregou exatamente a imagem como fundo ocupando a tela toda. Agora como faço para manter essa imagem (deixar ela mais clara) e sobrepor conteúdo à esse fundo?

Comment: Então, se a imagem foi aplicada ao body, qualquer coisa dentro dele (que ja seria a página inteira) ja vai sobrepor ela, posta uma screenshot da sua intenção pra entender mais fácil.

Comment: Se o que você estiver tentando fazer é manter a imagem fixa em relação a rolagem da página, você pode usar a propriedade `background-attachment:fixed;`

Answer (score 1):

Pode utilizar a propriedade [**`background-size`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size):

```css
body {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWdW6.jpg);
  background-size: cover
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Como o @re22 já disse, para que a imagem ocupe o tamanho todo da tela/ecrã por completo, podes utilizar a propriedade `background-size: cover;` e para que a imagem do background fique fixa conforme fazemos *scroll* de uma página/website, utiliza -  `background-attachment: fixed;`:

```
background-image: url(imagem.jpg);  /* URL da imagem pretendida */
background-repeat: no-repeat;       /* A imagem não é para ser repetida ao longo da página */
background-position-x: center;      /* alinhamento horizontal : left|center|right|px */
background-position-y: center;      /* alinhamento vertical: top|center|bottom|px */
background-attachment: fixed;       /* A imagem é para ficar fixa quando utilizada a Scrollbar */
-webkit-background-size: cover;     /* Navegadores Chrome, Safari */
-moz-background-size: cover;        /* Firefox */
-o-background-size: cover;          /* Opera */
background-size: cover;             /* Todos os outros. Imagem como 'capa' ocupando 100% altura/largura sem perder a sua proporção */
```

Eis um exemplo abaixo com o código simplificado utilizando apenas - `background:;` para adicionarmos todos estes estilos mencionados acima de uma só vez:

```css
body { 
    background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjGmV.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```